# AWK partial String search between two files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

File 2:

```
U1664246201||2020-03-01 00:00:00|2020-12-31 00:00:00|abc
U1664246201||2020-03-01 00:00:00|2020-12-31 00:00:00|abc
|R1664236401|2018-03-01 00:00:00|2020-12-31 00:00:00|abc    
U1664546501|R1664546401|2019-04-01 00:00:00|2020-12-30 00:00:00|abc
U1774546301||2020-05-01 00:00:00|2020-12-31 00:00:00|abc
```

File 1:

```
U17745463
R16645464
R16642364
```

Current Solution

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "columns"} {FS=OFS="|"} NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} {for (i in a) if($1 != "" && $2 != ""){if(index($1, i)){print $0} else {if(index($2, i)){print $0}} } else{ if((index($1, i)) || (index($2, i))){print $0}}}' file2.txt file1.txt > result.txt
```

Output:

```
|R1664236401|2018-03-01 00:00:00|2020-12-31 00:00:00|abc    
U1664546501|R1664546401|2019-04-01 00:00:00|2020-12-30 00:00:00|abc    
U1774546301||2020-05-01 00:00:00|2020-12-31 00:00:00|abc
```

This solution is giving the output but when processing million records it takes more time and sometimes hang. Is there any better solution for this problem?

Comment: I think the order of `file2.txt` and `file1.txt` should be swapped in your `awk`  example. 
Does your input of `file1` have to match at the beginning of the (first two) fields of `file2` or do you want matches anywhere in those fields? And can each input of `file1` have more than one match in `file2`?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 can you help me out on this?

Comment: You want to search values in file 1 are matching in column 1 of file 2 ?

Comment: Search file1 coulmn with file2 column1 or column2..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be just what `grep` was made for, so I guess it must be more efficient.

```
$ grep -f file1 file2
|R1664236401|2018-03-01 00:00:00|2020-12-31 00:00:00|abc
U1664546501|R1664546401|2019-04-01 00:00:00|2020-12-30 00:00:00|abc
U1774546301||2020-05-01  00:00:00|2020-12-31 00:00:00|abc

$ cat file1
U17745463
R16645464
R16642364

$ cat file2
U1664246201||2020-03-01 00:00:00|2020-12-31 00:00:00|abc
U1664246201||2020-03-01 00:00:00|2020-12-31 00:00:00|abc
|R1664236401|2018-03-01 00:00:00|2020-12-31 00:00:00|abc
U1664546501|R1664546401|2019-04-01 00:00:00|2020-12-30 00:00:00|abc
U1774546301||2020-05-01  00:00:00|2020-12-31 00:00:00|abc
```

Note that the `-f` option specifies the file from which the patterns are taken.

Comment: getting memory exhausted error for large files when using grep..

Comment: @rakeshkandukuri  Try adding `-F` to the grep options for fixed-string matching instead of regular expressions; might take less memory: `grep -Ff file1 file2`.

Answer (score 0):

If `perl` is your option, would you please try the following:

```
sort file1 > file1_sorted
sort -t "|" -k 1,1 file2 > file2_sorted_0       # sort by the 1st column
sort -t "|" -k 2,2 file2 > file2_sorted_1       # sort by the 2nd column

perl -e '

for $i (0 .. 1) {                               # repeat twice by changing the order of file2
    open(FH1, "file1_sorted") or die;           # set filehandle for file1_sorted
    open(FH2, "file2_sorted_$i") or die;        # set filehandle for file2_sorted_n

    while (!eof(FH1) || !eof(FH2)) {
        unless (defined $l1) {                  # if marked to update
            $l1 = <FH1>;                        # read next item from FH1
            chomp($l1);                         # remove the newline
        }
        unless (defined $l2) {                  # if marked to update
            $l2 = <FH2>;                        # read next item from FH2
            @ary = split(/\|/, $l2);            # split on "|"
        }
        if ($ary[$i] =~ /^$l1/) {               # test the match
            print $l2;                          # print the matched line
            undef $l1;                          # set mark to update FH1
        } else {
            if ($ary[$i] lt $l1) {              # if FH2 is less than FH1
                undef $l2;                      # set mark to update FH2
            } else {
                undef $l1;                      # else update FH1
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

- If we compare the two files line by line, it requires `O(N ** 2)`
  computation and will take a long time.
- In order to reduce the comparison, we sort the files in advance
  and compare the entries in the `stream` with the same manner as we do in the `pipeline merge sort`.
- As we have two columns to compare in `file2`, we prepare two files
  for `file2` by changing the sort keys.
- The same logic can be implemented with `awk` as well but let me use
  `perl` for this time.